# What is a word for "about to burst out laughing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can describe this facial expression?

[image]

*("about to burst out laughing")*

Comment: I don't think any artifice would have the same effect as the excellent phrase *about to burst out laughing*.   The reader should feel it within the continuity of context, without having to consult a dictionary (even an online one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture shows a laugh that is *[smothered](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/smother)*.

Answer (score 1):

Not a particularly common word even with its primary meaning of *impregnated with thorium oxide to increase thermionic emission*, but...

> **thoriated** - [tittering; being or sounding of nervous or suppressed laughter](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=thoriated)

Answer (score 1):

The face appears [contorted](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=ppwc&cp=8&gs_id=1p&xhr=t&q=contorted&pq=convulsed&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=contorte&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4af2d9e6c889c72a&biw=1280&bih=687) / [convulsed](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=convulsed&pbx=1&oq=convulsed&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=600l2694l0l2729l9l8l0l0l0l1l672l3120l0.1.1.0.1.4l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4af2d9e6c889c72a&biw=1280&bih=687) with suppressed laughter to me.