# Term for a snort that is almost a laugh

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a snort that is almost a laugh (as would occur when looking at a meme in a public space or any situation where something is humorous but it is not acceptable to outright laugh)?

Comment: chortle is not quite specific enough...

Comment: Just a few seconds ago I used "snort" (I might have used "snicker") just that way in a comment before reading your question.

Comment: You could start with [the _sn_-words](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf).

Comment: @Bill: You should probably post *snicker* as an answer. To some people it's synonymous with *snigger* (which usually implies *mocking* laughter at another's expense) - but I'm not one of them, so I'd upvote if you posted it. Of course, you might get *downvoted* by people who think it's too close to the dreaded n-word...

Comment: @Fu: I specifically avoided _snigger_ because of the _niggardly_ flap in DC some years ago. While I'm not particularly supportive of PC language, I feel obliged to avoid consciously saying or doing things that have a very good chance of being misunderstood by the hypersensitive hypo-perspicascious.

Comment: Related: _[What is a word for “about to burst out laughing”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50041/5822)_

Comment: What's wrong with "snort"?

Comment: Seriously? The PC crowd objects to _snigger_? That's ridiculous.

Comment: Snicker is a back formation specifically to avoid saying snigger.  So yes, they're the same word.

Comment: @KazDragon Snicker is the older word. Both from late 17th/early 18th century.

Comment: @JohnLawler what is that document you linked to? Is that describing how certain words came about? Is there something specific about "sn" words? Can you link me to something that explains what that is talking about in more detail?

Comment: @JimmyG. It's the list of English simplex words that begin with _sn-_, grouped by their meanings.  [Look here](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono) for some more of my research into English sound symbolism.

Comment: @JohnLawler WHOA that is technically dense. After I looked up two words whose definitions each required me to look up two words, I got frustrated. Then, when I had no idea about your notation, I gave up.  To be honest, I have no idea if your brilliant or delusional. lol. I may take a closer look at this when I can motivate myself a little better. Thank you, though. As a quick question, do assonances (new word for me) always, or even usually, share a root word?

Comment: Not a root word, but a semantic interpretation of the cluster (or rime, at the other end of the word). So [_kr-_](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/kr.pdf) has phonosemantics, but _skr-_ doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[whicker](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/whicker)** |ˈ(h)wɪkər|

> verb [ intrans. ]
>
> **1** utter a half-suppressed laugh; snigger; titter : *a half-loony whicker of nerves*.
>
> • (of a horse) give a soft breathy whinny : *the palomino whickered when she saw him and stamped her foreleg*.
>
> **2** move with a sound as of something hurtling through or beating the air : *the soft whicker of the wind flowing through the July corn*.
>
> noun
>
> **1** a snigger; a soft, breathy whinny.
>
> **2** the sound of something beating the air.

Answer (score 6):

It's slang, but there is the word [*snortle*.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snortle) It's defined as:

> A hearty laugh that is punctuated by a snort on the inhale.

Or the [Wordnik entry has it defined as:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/snortle)

> To snort; grunt.

Comment: *snerkles* What a silly word.

Answer (score -1):

snaughling - Laughing so hard you snort, then laugh because you snorted, then snort because you laughed!

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snaughling)

Comment: Could you please provide some support for this answer? Perhaps a link to a published definition?